# Access SharePoint Sites without sign-in account Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, authentication, share

I need to create scheduler in windows 10 to automatically open browser and my SharePoint sites on windows start up.

But condition in my browser right now doesn't have Office 365 session, so if the SharePoint site automatically open it need to login using account Office 365.

Can I access SharePoint site without sign in using account Office 365 (guest)?

Comment: Please describe what exactly you want to do after accessing site?

Answer (score 0):

Even guest accounts have to authenticate to access SharePoint Online (though you can sometimes use temporary codes to access sites).

It sounds as though you need to implement single sign-on. This would allow the browser to automatically sign the user in to SharePoint Online. More information can be found here:

[What is single sign-on in Azure Active Directory?](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on)